# Setting Up Wordpress on Local Server, not showing full site when I test on remote server (Intranet)

Tags: xampp

I am setting up an intranet that runs off of Wordpress through XAMPP. It's been set up on the local server which is port 80. 
Wordpress was also set up with the local server as the database.
I edited the hosts file to point to the correct IP address as well as the name of the newly created database that holds WordPress.

But when I test it on a remote server, it is not fully loading. 
Everything is connected and its reading right, but I am unable to fully load the whole page. It's just giving me a very basic text outline. My favicon loads, the title of the pages load and when I inspect the page source everything is there from the looks of it.

I appreciate all and any help!

Comment: Are you getting any 404 errors if you inspect the page?

Comment: "Everything is there" - do you mean all of your HTML is loading correctly? That would probably mean that the CSS and JS aren't all loading. Inspect those, or open the network tab to see if anything is erroring out.